# How to disable TLS 1.0 on Windows Server 2012 having 4.5 .Net Framework using registry keys

Tags: .net-4.5, windows-server-2012, tls1.2, tls1.0

Can anyone provide a solution to disable TLS 1.0 as default protocol on Windows Server 2012 Standard with 4.5 .Net Framework installed on the machine. The application running on the server have target framework of .NET 4.5 and is making connection with another server which have only TLS 1.2 enabled.

I have tried setting the below Registries but it is still making call on TLS1.0:

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS 1.2\Client]
"DisabledByDefault"=dword:00000000

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders\SCHANNEL\Protocols\TLS 1.2\Server]
"Enabled"=dword:00000001
"DisabledByDefault"=dword:00000000

Microsoft's documentation site only list the fix in code by setting the Security protocol as below

```
System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
```

But is there any way to achieve this via the registry?

Answer (score 1):

For anyone with similar problems:

Open PowerShell run as administrator: `[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol`

Notice the response is `Ssl3, Tls`

Run the following 2 commands in PowerShell

```
Set-ItemProperty -Path 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\.NetFramework\v4.0.30319' -Name 'SchUseStrongCrypto' -Value '1' -Type DWord

Set-ItemProperty -Path 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\.NetFramework\v4.0.30319' -Name 'SchUseStrongCrypto' -Value '1' -Type DWord
```

Close PowerShell, reopen as admin, run: `[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol`

Now notice the output, the system will work without using this code `System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;`

Output is: `Tls, Tls11, Tls12`

Disable the `Tls1` on the OS and it will negotiate `Tls12` if available.